# Getting into a sibling folder html

Tags: html

I have to link localhost/xyz/main.php from localhost/abc/main.php. How to do that?
I have tried like this..

code of abc/main.php:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li> <a href="/xyz/main.php">Think of Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is in script but where?

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li ").click(function(){
var presentURL = window.location.pathname;
// getting to the regarding menu

var liURL = $(this).find("a").attr('href');

var findMatch = function(){
var x = liURL.slice(0,liURL.indexOf("/"));
var frompresentURL =presentURL.search(x);
var fromliURL = liURL.search(x);

if (frompresentURL > -1 && fromliURL > -1) return true;
else return false;
}   


if (findMatch()){
    $(this).find("a").attr('href',liURL.slice(liURL.indexOf("/")+1));
    alert($(this).find("a").attr('href'));
}


})
```

But how did it create problem?

Comment: That should work if you have your `localhost` set up correctly.

Comment: localhost is always working.

Comment: Can you try adding a dot before the path? `<a href="./xyz/main.php">`?

Comment: Not working. double dot also not working.

Comment: When you hover over a link, the full address will be shown in the status bar. Compare this full address to your expectations.

Comment: The link is shown rightly i.e localhost/xyz/main.php. But when i click on this shows /abc/xyz/main.php not found. The problem is somewhere in script. I updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried logging your variables to see at which step the mistake might happen?

Comment: yes. if i cut findmatch function and the 'if' statement, the link works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="../xyz/main.php">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate up from the /abc folder then down into the /xyz folder.
Adding two fullstops to the href path means 'go up a folder'.

So the path "../xyz/main.php" means go up from the /abc folder to the parent folder then down into the /xyz folder and find main.php

Your html should look like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="../xyz/main.php">Think of Link</a></li>
</ul>
```